# Frame information in completion handler for text detection in ARSession

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, arkit, apple-vision

I am using Core Vision to detect text boxes in an ARKit session, my problem is accessing the `frame` to perform a hit test once I have detected the boxes.

```
func startTextDetection() {
    let textRequest = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.detectTextHandler)
    textRequest.reportCharacterBoxes = true
    self.requests = [textRequest]
}

func detectTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let observations = request.results else {
        print("no result")
        return
    }

    let result = observations.map({$0 as? VNTextObservation})
    for box in result {
        let hit = frame.hitTest(box?.topRight - box?.bottomLeft, types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint )
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform:hit.worldTransform)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor:anchor)
    }
    //DispatchQueue.main.async() {

    //}
}
```

Ideally I would pass it to the completion handler from the `ARSession` delegate method but although the documentation says I can pass a completion handler here, I hav not found a way to do it.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Retain the image buffer for Vision processing.
    let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
    let requestOptions:[VNImageOption : Any] = [:]

    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, options: requestOptions)

    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I can keep a dictionary and look it up but it is not really elegant and it is prone to bugs and leaks. I would rather pass the relevant frame where I request the text detection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use your session's `currentFrame` property inside the completion handler? It contains the current frame of the session. Plus you don't need to pass any `frame` instance to your completion handler anymore. It is simply accessible using your `sceneView` instance.

So you can change your completion handler like below:

```
func detectTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else { return }
    ...
    // perform hit test using currentFrame
    let hit = currentFrame.hitTest(box?.topRight - box?.bottomLeft, types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint ) 
    ...
}
```

You can use `currentFrame` to create the image request handler in `session(_:didUpdate:)` as well:

```
let pixelBuffer = sceneView.currentFrame.capturedImage
```

Also, note that firing `perform()` method of `VNImageRequestHandler` in `session(_:didUpdate:)` is not efficient and takes so much process since it's running all the time, you could use a `Timer` instead to reduce amounts of time you perform image detection process.

---

Edit: Since image detection is async and might take time to finish, you can store the frame in another instance when making request, and use that instance inside completion handler:

```
var detectionFrame: ARFrame?

// Timer block
detectionFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame
let pixelBuffer = detectionFrame.capturedImage
// image detection request code


func detectTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let frame = detectionFrame else { return }
    ...
    let hit = frame.hitTest(box?.topRight - box?.bottomLeft, types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint ) 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but depending on process time / latency the current frame could be different from the frame that was used to detect the text. Good idea on the timer.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini it won’t be different if you use currentFrame in both sides I guess?

Comment: the detection is async, so if the detection takes half a second and in the meantime I turned the camera it would

Comment: @DanieleBernardini you're right. I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, as I am not processing more than a frame at the time (doh!) I can just use the detectionFrame as lock to prevent new detection to start and clear it once the detection has completed

Comment: On a different topic, there is no tag for coreml vision framework ... I can't create i yet but you can ;-)